# Tomcat server does not start and says "internal error occur launching ... org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel

Tags: tomcat7, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using Ubunt 12.04. My project was running fine till yesterday and today when i open the springtoolsuit and start tomcat (i am using tomcat 7.0), a pop up opens and says:

In details it says :
An internal error occurred during: "Starting tomcat_server_name**".
org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel

Can i be issue due to ubuntu updates ??

** Tomcat_server_name is the name of my tomcat server.

Kindly help me, as i searched google alot but could not found any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as it may help some one like me facing the same problem.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

solve the problem.
Got solution from
[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186986/eclipse-has-multiple-issues-after-jre-6-openjdk-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, there is another solution. Open eclipse.ini in the Eclipse installation folder and add -Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU as the last line of that file

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 16.04, there is no tzdata-java package. I guess it got rolled in to tzdata, but reinstalling it does not fix this problem. I fixed it by downgrading tzdata to the last version that was accompanied by tzdata-java, then reinstalling tzdata-java.

tzdata: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/tzdata/2016c-0ubuntu1

tzdata-java: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/tzdata-java/2016c-0ubuntu1

I have to keep using the old version for Tomcat7 to work, so did this to prevent Ubuntu from updating the file:

```
sudo apt-mark hold tzdata
```

Answer (score 0):

re-installing and selecting JDK 1.8 worked for me in Xubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

sudo update-alternatives --config java
```